# Mocking out a function on a repeated call with Python mock

Tags: python-2.7, mocking

I'd like to test a recursive function and then mock that same function out. For the first call, I want to actually call the function **as it appears in my module**. When it calls itself, I'd like to mock out the call using [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) and specify the return value of this second recursive call.

A really simple example of what I mean:

```
def some_function(input_value):
    if input_value == some_appropriate_value:
        return foo
    else:
        return some_function(some_other_value)
```

How do I mock out `some_function` the second time it is called? If I use something like a @mock.patch decorator, I can't actually test it as `some_function` **will be mocked out for all calls**.

Any suggestions of how to do this? I couldn't find any obvious Stack Overflow questions discussing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you save the function before patching you can call the correct version.

```
copy_of_foo = foo
with patch('...foo') as foo_mock:
   copy_of_foo(args...)
```

In order to get your patched function to call differently you can try a few things: 1. side_effects and 2. subclassing a mock object to override the function call and keep a counter.